# How to call method in Controller from View on a javascript event in RoR?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

I am new to RoR. I have a view file which uses javascript. Upon clinking a button, I want to call a method in Controller. How do I do that.

JS code: **(folder_view.js)**

```
function iterate(data){

    var folder_names = "";

    $.each(data.Folder, function(key, val) {
        folder_names = folder_names + "<ul> <li id= '" + val.folder_name + "'>
<a class='a' href='' onclick='updateDiv(val.folder_name)'>" + val.folder_name + 
"</a></li></ul>";
    });

    var divid = "folder";
    var view_var2 = jQuery("<div class='scrollbar ' id='divscroll' > <div class='content ' id = " + divid + "> <ul> <li> Folder " + folder_names + "</li></ul></div></div>");

    $('#folder_view').html(view_var2);

    tree_view(divid);

}

function tree_view(divid){
    $("#" + divid).jstree();
    $("#" + divid).on("changed.jstree", function (e, data) {
      console.log(data.selected);
    });
    $('button').on('click', function () {
        $("#" + divid).jstree(true).select_node('child_node_1');
        $("#" + divid).jstree('select_node', 'child_node_1');
        $.jstree.reference("#" + divid).select_node('child_node_1');
    });
}
```

Here, I am calling the UpdateDiv method upon clinking on folder. This method is available in view file which is as follows:

Folder_view.html.erb:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js" ></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="/assets/folder_view.js"></script>    
<script type="text/javascript" src="/assets/jstree.min.js"></script>    

<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $.getJSON('/assets/temp.json', function(data) {
            iterate(data);
        });
    });

    function updateDiv(data){
        //Call a function to controller
    }

</script>

<body class="bonita-body" ieonload="">

<div id="bonita_process_label" class="bonita_process_label"><div class="gwt-HTML">Console</div></div>
<div id="bonita-banneralthaut"></div>
<div id="bonita-banneraltbas"></div>
<div style='margin-top: 40px;'> <div id='folder_view'></div>

</body>
```

The method updateDiv is being called upon clicking a folder_name. I want fetch some folder-specific meta-data from controller for the same. How do I call any method from view to controller upon clinking?

Any references??

Answer (score 0):

You need to make an AJAX call using either native XHR:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest

OR by using jQuery AJAX:

https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/